# file name automatically change when i upload the file

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-2

I'm new to CodeIgniter and having the following issue. When I upload a file, its successfully uploaded on my local folder and the file name saved to the db. The problem is, file name has been changed after uploading.
eg:
file name "screenshot image 123.png" -> "screenshot_image_123.png"
It just convert the space into underscore;this issue occurred only when the file name having space.Other than this issue all the other files uploading successfully. Given below is my code which I used on my controller page:

```html
public function upload_pic()
{
               $image_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');
               $config['upload_path'] = $image_path;
               $config['allowed_types'] =   "gif|jpg|jpeg|png";
               $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
               $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; 
               $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
               $this->load->library('upload',$config);
               $this->upload->initialize($config);  
               if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file'))
               {
                        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
               }
               else
               {
                        $finfo=$this->upload->data();
                        $data['uploadInfo'] = $finfo;
               }
}
```

Can anyone help me????

Comment: Better generate unique file name and save that for filename and db

Comment: is there any option in codeigniter, by which we can prevent codeigniter to change file name automatically.?? for example i am saving files with same name of any IDs and want to match both in future, so.

Answer (score 0):

Try before saving file name generate some unique

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$filename = sha1_file($filename). md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u')) . '.'. $ext; //not only this you can generate any format



$config['file_name'] = $filename; //Use this file name is db too
```

Comment: Hi @vijay4vijju, Its working for me.. Thanks for your prompt help.

Comment: When i insert the file its working fine. But I am unable to edit the file. Can you figure it out?

Comment: I Think it should work for both cases.  What the problem are you getting any errors ? Can you post the edit code?

Comment: public function update(){$mdata['id']=$_POST['id'];
$mdata['name']=$_POST['name'];
$mdata['harddisk']=$_POST['harddisk'];
$mdata['ram']=$_POST['ram'];
$mdata['screen']=$_POST['screen'];
$mdata['processer']=$_POST['processer'];
$mdata['active']=$_POST['active'];
$mdata['file']=$_POST['file'];
$res=$this->user_model->update_info($mdata, $_POST['id']);
if($res){header('location:'.base_url()."login/".$this->index());                        }}

Comment: Insted of "$mdata['file']=$_POST['file'];" this again you should follow same step's of for uploading image as above in your question.  and you u get new filename you should update that filename. Or if you want to update same filename remove "$mdata['file']=$_POST['file'];"  line and try.